# How do I solve a FROM keyword error in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, escaping, identifier

I tried doing the query for the assingment:

```
select invoice_number, vendor_id,
       payment_total - invoice_total AS 'Reamaining Total' 
from invoices;
```

But I keep getting this error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected:

> 923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
>      *Cause:
>      *Action:
>      Error at Line: 14 Column: 68

Answer (score 1):

Use double, not single, quotes to escape identifiers in Oracle SQL:

```sql
SELECT invoice_number, vendor_id,
       payment_total - invoice_total AS "Remaining Total"
FROM invoices;
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes should be used *only* for string and date constants.  Try writing the query without escaping any identifiers:

```
select invoice_number, vendor_id,
       (payment_total - invoice_total) AS remaining_total
from invoices;
```